# How to Create small TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield

I want to reduce space between line and text with flutter.
[image]

```
SizedBox(
                        width: 60.0,
                        child: TextField(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: '125',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of wrapping `TextField` inside `SizedBox` use `constraints` property of `Input Decoration` to give the TextField min or max height/width:

```
TextField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: '125',
      isDense: true,
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxWidth: 60
      )
    ),
  )
```

Comment: It doesnt work, i mean like make the space closer between line and the text
https://imgur.com/a/mSmfrEV

Comment: Okay, your question was unclear. Set `isDense` property to `true` to reduce the space between text and underline. (check the updated code)

Comment: Or, if you want to reduce the space even more then use `isCollapsed` instead of `isDense`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `InputDecoration()` set the `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero`. And set `isDense: true`